# Kafka 2.0.0 consume slow when subscribe multiple topics by pattern

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

Recently we setup a new kafka cluster(version 2.0.0) installed by ambari. We have multiple topics like prefix_{yyyy-MM-dd} which are created every day and delete topics which are two weeks before. So in the most case there are 14 topics existing but only 1 topic receives data. Our program subscribes topics with a pattern "prefix_.*". The problem is that it consumes very very slow. When we replaced the pattern with fixed 1 topic like prefix_2020-09-28, it works well. I think the possible reason maybe that it subscribe 14 topics although 13 of them don't have any new data coming. But our old kafka cluster(version 1.0.1) works fine under the same circumstance. Any idea to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

P.S. We use Flume and Flink to consume kafka and they both have this issue.

Comment: How many partitions do you have per topic? Can you make sure that they are somewhat evenly filled?

Comment: 18 partitions. I am sure it is evenly distributed and every single partitions is consumed very slow.